# Microservices: Fetching information or checking if it exists via another service

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I am just trying to wrap my head around some basic microservice arhitecture concepts, and have read that it's recommended to call other services from a service as this would introduce coupling.

Consider the following:

[image: basic microservice architecture]

This is a restful API, and to create a listing I would be sending a `terrainId` param along with the rest of the data, however, if I was to not call another service within a service, how would I validate that that `terrainId` passed in is actually valid and exists within the Terrain service?

In addition to this, getting a listing, say I want to return the terrain details (`title`, `description` etc) in the response to my API call (`GET /listing`) if I am unable to call a service from within a service?

Same kind of things would apply to the recommendations engine?

There is one other service I would be implementing, this would be search, but would be driven by Opensearch so would likely have the related information within the record in Opensearch.

If you haven't guessed, I am planning on using AWS services (Api Gateway, Lambda's, Dynamo etc.).